# Find a date in mongodb

Tags: php, json, mongodb, mongodb-query

Since I've realized that I can't compare ($gt, $gte, $lt, $lte, etc) dates in String format  I'm trying to learn how to use **UTCDateTime**.
and I'm not able to find a date in a collection with MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime

I'm trying with this code.

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new MongoDB\client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$database = $client->db;
$center = $database->collection;

$document = $center->find(array("date" => new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime("2018-03-22T09:03:07.147Z")));
foreach ($document as $doc){
        var_dump($doc);
}
```

And the JSON I have is this one.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5ab3714bb57dce13040024c3"),
    "name" : "16floor",
    "date" : ISODate("2018-03-22T09:03:07.147Z"),
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "value" : 169
        }, 
        {
            "value" : 200
        }, 
        {
            "value" : 80
        },
        .
        .
        .
```

I'm getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Error parsing
>   "2018-03-22T09:03:07.147Z" as 64-bit integer for
>   MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime initialization

How could I find a date in a collection with MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime?

As far as i know I also can find a date with a timestamp, but I'm looking for a search with **UTCDateTime** field.

Answer (score 1):

According to [UTCDateTime::__construct](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.construct.php) documentation string as an argument should contain number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (and it is available only for compatibility with 32-bit systems). To get your code to work you need to pass an instance of `\DateTimeInterface`:

```
new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(new \DateTimeImmutable("2018-03-22T09:03:07.147Z"))
```